# My VB script runs as long as I don't switch windows by clicking "Alt + Tab". Why?

Tags: excel, vba

The script works perfectly.
Except if I don't press "Alt + Tab" 2-3 times it will take at least another 30 minutes to finish. But If I switch using "Alt + Tab" it finishes in less than 2 minutes.

My question is  :

1. Is it due to improper use of loops ?
2. Is it Due to number of function calls I have used ?
3. Or the code itself is inefficient ?

Please let me know if I have missed any relevant info.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Interfac 
    Call DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria
    Call DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria2
    GenerateReport Worksheets("Report_Template"), Worksheets("Jira"), Worksheets("Script")
    Call Deleterows
    Call DefaultData    
    MsgBox "Report Generation Finished!"
End Sub

Public costcenterswitch As Long

Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
Dim RowToTest As Long
Sheets("Jira").Select
For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    With Cells(RowToTest, 2)
        If .Value = "CVEI-VR " _
        Or .Value = "All Issues" _
        Then _
        Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
Next RowToTest
End Sub

Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria2()
Dim RowToTest As Long
Sheets("Jira").Select
For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    With Cells(RowToTest, 1)
        If .Value = "All Assignees" _
        Then _
        Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
Next RowToTest
End Sub

Sub DefaultData()
    For Row = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Cells(Row, 1).Formula = 1
        Cells(Row, 3).Formula = "SVDO"
        Cells(Row, 4).Formula = costcenterswitch
        Cells(Row, 5).Formula = "PS_99999"
        Cells(Row, 9).Formula = 999
        Cells(Row, 10).Formula = "EWH"
        Cells(Row, 12).Formula = "H"
        Cells(Row, 13).Formula = 0
        Cells(Row, 14).Formula = 0
        Cells(Row, 2).Formula = Row - 1
    Next Row
End Sub

Sub Deleterows()
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("K").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Sub Interfac()
Sheets("Script").Select
If IsEmpty(Range("O3").Value) = False Then
    costcenterswitch = Range("O3").Value
Else
    costcenterswitch = 900214
End If
End Sub

Sub GenerateReport(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet)

 Dim report As Workbook
 Set report = Workbooks.Add
 Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
 Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
 Dim Row As Long, col As Integer, row3 As Integer, col3 As Integer, runsthirtyonetimes As Integer

    With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1row = .Rows.Count
    ws1col = .Columns.Count
    End With

    With ws2.UsedRange
    ws2row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
    End With

    maxrow = ws1row
    maxcol = ws1col
    If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
    If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

    Row = 1
    For col = 1 To ws1col
        Cells(Row, col).Formula = ws1.Cells(Row, col).Formula
        Cells(Row, col).Font.Bold = True
    Next col

    counter = 2
        For Row = 2 To ws2row
            For runsthirtyonetimes = 1 To 31
                Cells(counter, 7).Formula = ws2.Cells(Row, 2).Formula
                Cells(counter, 8).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                Cells(counter, 8).Formula = ws2.Cells(Row, counter).Formula
                Cells(counter, 11).Formula = ws2.Cells(Row, counter).Formula
                If ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(3, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(3, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(4, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(4, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(5, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(5, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(6, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(6, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(7, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(7, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(8, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(8, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(9, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(9, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(10, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(10, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(11, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(11, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(12, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(12, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(13, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(13, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(14, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(14, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(15, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(15, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(16, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(16, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(17, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(17, 17).Formula
                ElseIf ws2.Cells(Row, 1).Formula = ws3.Cells(18, 16).Formula Then
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = ws3.Cells(18, 17).Formula
                Else
                    Cells(counter, 6).Formula = "BAD ID"
                    Cells(counter, col).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
                    Cells(counter, col).Font.Bold = True
                End If
                counter = counter + 1
            Next runsthirtyonetimes
        Next Row
        counter = 2
        For Row = 2 To ws2row
            For runsthirtyonetimes = 4 To 34
                Cells(counter, 8).Formula = ws2.Cells(1, runsthirtyonetimes).Formula
                Cells(counter, 11).Formula = ws2.Cells(Row, runsthirtyonetimes).Formula
                counter = counter + 1
            Next runsthirtyonetimes
        Next Row
        Columns("A:Z").ColumnWidth = 20
        Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 60
        Rows("1:100").RowHeight = 15
    End Sub
```

Comment: Qualify all your unqualified `range`, `cells`, `columns` calls, otherwise they implicitly refer to whatever sheet/workbook happens to be active whilst the code is running. This means you need to explicitly need to specify in your code what sheet/workbook the `range/cells/columns` belong to.

Comment: Can you point out one of the unqualified range.cells.columns @chillin ?

Comment: Same goes for your Rows. You are, in places, using .Select to activate a sheet. It would be faster to use a With worksheets("sheetname") construct..... Example unqualified:  Cells(Row, 1).Formula = 1

Comment: Was this code originally in several modules as you have a Public variable declaration hanging out lower in the code.

Comment: One example of an unqualified reference would be in your `DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria` procedure, `For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row...`. Even though you `Select` the intended parent worksheet on the line before, the call to `Cells(Rows...` is in and of itself unqualified. Also I think your `DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria` and `DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria2` can be written using `Range.AutoFilter`. It should be faster, less verbose and easier to maintain, as you won't be deleting one row at a time. I want to put `Thisworkbook` before all of your worksheets, but you said this is a VBScript?

Comment: You guys made my day. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work across multiple sheets, clarifying the cell or range of sheets will reduce errors and improve speed. The code below illustrates what you are missing.

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()

Dim RowToTest As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Sheets("Jira")
With Ws
    For RowToTest = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        With .Cells(RowToTest, 2) '<~~ ws.Cells(RowToTest, 2) 
            If .Value = "CVEI-VR " _
            Or .Value = "All Issues" _
            Then _
            Ws.Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next RowToTest
End Sub
```